# How to prevent qtip overlapping

Tags: jqgrid, qtip2, qtip, mousehover, jqxgrid

How to prevent qtip overlaps when mouse hovering on another cells.
The issue is that the qtip is not hidden immediately when mouse left and when the mouse is hovered on another cell, the previous one is also visible.

Code:

```
$(event.target).qtip({
                                content: { text: tooltiptext, title: { text: "Info", button: 'Close' } },
                                show: {
                                    event: 'mouseover',
                                    ready: true
                                },
                                hide: {
                                    event: 'mouseout'
                                },
                                position: {

                                    my: 'center',
                                    at: 'bottom left',
                                    adjust: {
                                        screen: true
                                    }
                                },
                            });
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Documentation:http://qtip2.com/options#show.solo. You could set `show.solo` to true(Default false).when set true,only show one tooltip at a time.

Here is an example of what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/Andy_wang_ke/fhbnoojd/4/

I hope this helps